# Packed struct bitfield vs #define'd bitmasks

Tags: c, data-structures, avr, avr-gcc

I have an AVR program which stores a set (usually less than 8) bit flags in a static status variable (which is contained inside a struct holding various other state fields of the module).

if it more or less efficient to do it like this:

```
#define STATUS_ENABLED 0x01

struct DeviceState {
    uint8_t status;
}

static struct DeviceState myState;

//and somewhere in the program...
myState.status |= STATUS_ENABLED;
```

Or do it with a packed bitfield:

```
struct DeviceState {
    uint8_t enabled : 1;
}

static struct DeviceState myState;

//and somewhere in the program...
myState.enabled = 1; // could use TRUE/FALSE if defined
```

Answer (score 3):

With avr-gcc 4.3.3, it seems there is no difference in implementation:

```
#define STATUS_ENABLE

struct DeviceState {
    uint8_t status;
    uint8_t enabled : 1;
}

static struct DeviceState myState;

//and this code...
myState.status |= STATUS_ENABLED;
myState.enabled = 1;
```

produces the following assembly code:

```
    myState.status |= STATUS_ENABLE;
00003746  LDS R24,0x20B5            Load direct from data space 
00003748  ORI R24,0x01              Logical OR with immediate 
00003749  STS 0x20B5,R24            Store direct to data space 

    myState.enabled = TRUE;
0000374B  LDS R24,0x20B4            Load direct from data space 
0000374D  ORI R24,0x01              Logical OR with immediate 
0000374E  STS 0x20B4,R24            Store direct to data space
```

So the same instructions (except for the address!).

Answer (score 2):

The bit field version is non-portable and the actual location of the bits is poorly defined. Apart from that, there should be no differences. Therefore, use the former version, since it is 100% portable.

Answer (score -2):

The packed bitfield allows you to store additional variables in a 8 bit memory space, so it would be more memory efficient if you are going to add more variables to DeviceStatus.